# How to remove a branch named "--orphan"

Tags: git

So I was trying to create an orphan branch. I tried a couple of things and one of them (`git checkout -b --orphan newbranch`) managed to create a branch called "--orphan"; now it won't let me delete it using `git branch -d --orphan`. I've also tried using quotes and escape characters. Nothing seems to work. I also tried using gitg to delete and to rename the branch; this didn't work.

How can I delete this branch?

Comment: +1 Funny. Oh wait, this isn't slashdot...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git branch -d -- --orphan
```

Everything after `--` is taken as an argument and not a switch.  This works in many places in git (and in many other Unix programs).